# Create an Historic Outlook MailItem - set details of SentOn

Tags: c#, email, outlook, interop

I need to migrate a large number of emails from Lotus Notes to a Outlook MSG format.

I need to ensure that the MSG's represent the emails in their original Lotus Notes format, including date sent, sent by, etc, and all attachments.

I have created LotusScript code to extract the email data and attachments from the Lotus Notes databases and store in a SQL database with attachments on a file store. I now need to work on code to read this data and create the Outlook messages. I have the scaffolding of a C# .Net application in place, but am struggling with being able to set read-only properties of the Outlook message, such as SentOn.

How do I/Can I set the read-only properties of the Outlook MailItem?

Comment: You're saving this on an exchange server or a local outlook db? If an exchange server, maybe look at EWS instead of interop?

Comment: I'm creating the MSG's locally so i can the upload to an existing application that stores binaries in a SQL filestream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you importing the messages to Outlook first?

If you only need to create standalone MSG files, you can use Redemption (I am its author) and its [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`CreateMessageFromMsgFile` method -it returns an instance of  the `RDOMail` object. You can set various `RDOMail` properties and call `RDOMail.Save`.

Comment: Im looking into Redemption, but having problems with the session, getting an invalid OS or OS version. I am on Win 8 64-bit, and registry is pointing to 64 bit redemption dll.

Comment: Is the bitness of your code matching the bitness of Outlook? http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#ErrorCreatingRedemptionObject